# What guarantees that the adjoint of a suitable integral operator, e.g. a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, is again an integral operator with a kernel?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, riesz-representation-theorem, integral-operators

This is likely a silly question, but I was wondering if $T$ is some nice integral transform, e.g. a Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator, with an, say, $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ kernel, what then guarantees that the adjoint of $T$ is again an integral operator with a kernel? If

$$Tf(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)k(x,y)dy$$

then we know that $$\|Tf\|\leq \|k\|\|f\|$$

in $L^2$ and the Ries representation theorem guarantess the existence of $T^*$. But how can we justify representing $T^*f$ as

$$T^*f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)s(x,y)dy$$

for some $s(.,.)$? Or is it so that in general we only know that the adjoints of some suitable classes of operators, like those of the Hilbert-Schmidt ones, have such representations?

Comment: Just apply Fubini to find what $s(x,y)$ is.